# List of available SQL Databases w/ VB>NET

Tags: sql, vb.net

Looking to get a list of available databases from a user defined sql server.  The code below properly queries available servers but now I'm trying to find the available databases on the selected server.

Thoughts?

```
Dim dt As Data.DataTable = Nothing, dr As Data.DataRow = Nothing
dt = System.Data.Sql.SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources()

For Each dr In dt.Rows
    cbAvailableSQLServers.Items.Add(dr.Item(0).ToString)
Next
```

Comment: My thoughts are: what is the problem?

Comment: I can query the available servers but now trying to get a list of available databases and then onto tables and stored procedures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, your code is going to get default instances OK but will not show the names of named instances.  Here's how I've populated a `ComboBox` with SQL Server instances in the past:

```
Private Sub serverCombo_DropDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles serverCombo.DropDown
    If Me.populateServerList Then
        'Enumerate available SQL Server instances.'
        Dim serverTable As DataTable = SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources()
        Dim upperBound As Integer = serverTable.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim serverNames(upperBound) As String

        For index As Integer = 0 To upperBound
            If serverTable.Rows(index).IsNull("InstanceName") Then
                serverNames(index) = CStr(serverTable.Rows(index)("ServerName"))
            Else
                serverNames(index) = String.Format("{0}\{1}", _
                                                   serverTable.Rows(index)("ServerName"), _
                                                   serverTable.Rows(index)("InstanceName"))
            End If
        Next

        Dim currentServerName As String = Me.serverCombo.Text

        With Me.serverCombo
            .BeginUpdate()
            .Items.Clear()
            .Items.AddRange(serverNames)
            .SelectedItem = currentServerName
            .Text = currentServerName
            .EndUpdate()
        End With

        Me.populateServerList = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Here's how I populated the database list for a server in the same application:

```
Private Sub databaseCombo_DropDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles databaseCombo.DropDown
    Using connection As New SqlConnection(Me.GetConnectionString(False))
        Try
            connection.Open()

            'Enumerate available databases.'
            Me.databaseCombo.DataSource = connection.GetSchema("Databases")
        Catch
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to connect.", _
                            "Connection Error", _
                            MessageBoxButtons.OK, _
                            MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try
    End Using
End Sub

Private Function GetConnectionString(ByVal includeDatabase As Boolean) As String
    Dim builder As New SqlConnectionStringBuilder()

    'Build a connection string from the user input.'
    builder.DataSource = Me.serverCombo.Text
    builder.IntegratedSecurity = Me.integratedSecurityOption.Checked
    builder.UserID = Me.userText.Text
    builder.Password = Me.passwordText.Text

    If includeDatabase Then
        builder.InitialCatalog = Me.databaseCombo.Text
    End If

    Return builder.ConnectionString
End Function
```

Comment: Note that you can use the same `SqlConnection.GetSchema` method to get a list of tables in a database too, if you include the database in the connection string.

Comment: What is builder.IntegratedSecurity = ?

That isn't resolving and I'm not clear on what its purpose is.  I can get the list of servers but connecting to the database is failing with an invalid user.

Comment: I'm not here to spoon feed you.  That property has existed since .NET 2.0 so if you're not getting Intellisense it's because you're not doing it properly.  You know what type it's a member of so look it up in the documentation.  There's a Help menu in VS for a reason.  Regardless of anything else, that method simply gets a connection string.  Surely you know how to build a connection string for yourself even without that code.

Comment: Never meant to come across as asking for spoon feeding.

I did some querying on Google and have it working properly.  I can now connect to the server.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad you got it working but that querying on Google should have been the first thing you did and posting back here for more information the last.

Comment: .DataSource = connection.GetSchema("Databases") results in the combobox being filled with "System.data.DataRowView"; one entry for each expected table name.

Comment: So set the `DisplayMember` property to the name of the column you want to display. That's not something I should have to explain. It's basic data-binding.

Answer (score 0):

You can either query sys.databases to get list of databases for a particular server instance or you need to use Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo namespace to programmatically query them